# Python Hive/hadoop connection error

Tags: python, hadoop

I am trying to use Hive/Hadoop using python.

```
import pyhs2
with pyhs2.connect(host='localhost',
               port=10000,
               authMechanism="PLAIN",
               user='None',
               password='None',
               database='Default') as conn:
with conn.cursor() as cur:
    #Show databases
    print cur.getDatabases()

    #Execute query
    cur.execute("select * from table")

    #Return column info from query
    print cur.getSchema()

    #Fetch table results
    for i in cur.fetch():
        print i
```

I am getting the following error.

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "pyth_hive2.py", line 8, in <module>
        database='Default') as conn:
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyhs2/__init__.py", line 7, in connect
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyhs2/connections.py", line 46, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyhs2/cloudera/thrift_sasl.py", line 74, in open
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyhs2/cloudera/thrift_sasl.py", line 92, in _recv_sasl_message
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 58, in readAll
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 94, in read
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: None
```

Can someone tell me how to go about this?

Comment: Try using small letter "default" as the name of the database.